# Creating a new folder and copying the current files to the new folder with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to SBT and in a build.sbt file. and trying to move folders from one folder to another.  Looking at the SBT documentation is not very helpful.  What I am trying to do is create a folder called b and copy a and its contents to b.

mkdir b
cp a to b resulting  in b/a

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use sbt task : https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html

add to `build.sbt`

```
val cp = Def.taskKey[Unit]("copy file")

cp := {
  import java.nio.file.Files
  import java.nio.file.Paths
  def copyDir(from: java.nio.file.Path, to: java.nio.file.Path): Unit = {
    if(!Files.exists(to.resolve(from)))
      Files.copy(from, to.resolve(from))
    if(from.toFile.isDirectory) {
      from.toFile.listFiles().toList.map(_.toPath).foreach(f => copyDir(f, to))
    }
  }

  val from = Paths.get("src") // your dir

  val to = Paths.get("to")
  if(!Files.exists(to))
    Files.createDirectory(to)
  copyDir(
    from,
    to
  )

}
```

execute cmd `sbt cp` , will copy file

Comment: This works great.  Thank you.  Now I am trying to do something like.  copy folder a to folder b/c making the resultant folder structure be b/c/a. 
I can create a shell script to create the c folder under b and then use the script above to copy a to b/c.